# Changes from a branch in the source code but visualy distinct

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ide

You know it when you start making changes in the code in IDE, you have them colored differently on the side to just mark them as divergent from what the last git commit was.
Unfortunately, in the new company we use the worst of them all, bitbucket, and doing code review on it is a no-no.
I came up with the idea to see the changes from the reviewed branch in the IDE marked just as you were making the changes yourself without committing, so I can see what was changed but also have all the other code right there to look it up. Is there a way of achieving it?
I dont want to play with opening a window for each file changed, it's extremely counterproductive.

I tried pulling the branch and merging with squash to a new one from master but Intellij  was showing no changes.